# Which version of protoc should I need?

Tags: gem5

When I ran the gem5 in a server, the error appeared.

> [libprotobuf FATAL google/protobuf/stubs/common.cc:68] This program requires version 3.5.0 of the Protocol Buffer runtime library, but the installed version is 3.4.0.  Please update your library.  If you compiled the program yourself, make sure that your headers are from the same version of Protocol Buffers as your link-time library.  (Version verification failed in "build/X86_MESI_Two_Level/proto/inst_dep_record.pb.cc".)
> terminate called after throwing an instance of 'google::protobuf::FatalException'
> what():  This program requires version 3.5.0 of the Protocol Buffer runtime library, but the installed version is 3.4.0.  Please update your library.  If you compiled the program yourself, make sure that your headers are from the same version of Protocol Buffers as your link-time library.  (Version verification failed in "build/X86_MESI_Two_Level/proto/inst_dep_record.pb.cc".)
> Aborted (core dumped)

According to the error information, I need version 3.5.0 of libprotobuf. But when I ran the command `protoc --version`, The output is "libprotoc 3.5.0" which shows that I already have version 3.5.0.
The same code can be run in another server. I run the command `protoc --version` in that server. It shows
"libprotoc 2.6.1".

Comment: I'm not sure why this happens, I would guess that the linker is finding the wrong protoc, different from what you have in the PATH. You can try to change link options with `scons LDFLAGS_EXTRA=...`. gem5 builds nightly in Docker Ubuntu 20.04 as shown at: https://askubuntu.com/questions/350475/how-can-i-install-gem5/1275773#1275773 and that has 3.6: https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/libprotobuf-dev